# Maximum work done between two states

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider two states - state1 (P1, V1, T1) and state2 (P2, V2, T2) - between which an ideal gas can undergo thermodynamic processes.

Its said that, the work done between these two states is maximum when its done reversibly.
But work is path function and there can be infinite number of paths taken between above two states.
So which path will given maximum work?

I can think of the one plotted below give maximum work wherein the ideal gas at state 1 follows isochoric, isobaric and again isochoric process to reach state2.
Is this correct? So we can get infinite amount of work done reversibly?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by $P_{infinite}$ on your graph?

Comment: @BobD its the maximum P we can take the gas to, for ideal gas it can be infinite, right? The point here is, to obtain maximum work.

Comment: Work is $\int pdV$. For a constant pressure process it is $p(V_{2}-V_1)$. So you don't have to increase the pressure to get more work. You can increase the volume as well. Infinite pressure and/or infinite volume change is not practical.

Comment: So you do agree, in ideal scenario, we can get infinite work done for above two states?

Comment: @BobD I have followup questions -
When they say maximum work can be obtained when process is done reversibly, here maximum work is compared to what? Can it be uniquely shown for above process ? Thanks.

Comment: Who says that the work is maximum when it's reversible?  You can insert as many Carnot cycles as you want into the path, and get any amount of work that you desire.

Comment: @ChetMiller got your point. So I guess we are being too liberal here ? I am missing the practical point of view here? In theory anything is possible but practically there are constraints which brings us to the stated maximum work concept?

Comment: The constraints to this kind of thing that I am familiar with are that the system is in contact with a single ideal constant temperature reservoir at the same temperature as the initial temperature of the system, and with a constant pressure surroundings at the same pressure as the initial pressure of the system.